# Insertar valores en una fila con auto-increment

Tags: mysql

Necesito saber cómo insertar datos en la fila de una tabla en la cual uno de los campos es un auto-increment. La tabla, llamada 'empleados', ya tiene unos 30 registros y el 'codigoempleado' es la columna auto-increment, que va por el número 30.

Yo he probado a introducir lo siguiente:

```
insert into empleados values(default, 'perico', 'palotes', 'de dios', 4587, 'email@email.com', 'MADR-ES', 3, 'Representante ventas')
```

Especificando: la primera columna de la tabla, al ser un auto-increment, he pensado en meterle un valor "default" pero parece que no funciona, y meter una constante '31', que es el siguiente número que debería aparecer no me parece lo más correcto.

EDIT: No puedo meterle un null, la columna es not null.

Se me ha ocurrido también que puede funcionar si especifico todas las columnas menos esta y les introduzco sus valores, pero me parece que no es la mejor solución y debe haber algo más que se pueda hacer.

¿Qué debería pues meter en el primer valor de la sentencia insert para que se rellente el campo auto-increment automáticamente?¿Hay alguna palabra clave para que el campo se autorellene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según la documentación de MySQL, lo recomendado es insertar NULL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

> An integer or floating-point column can have the additional attribute AUTO_INCREMENT. When you insert a value of **NULL (recommended)** or 0 into an indexed AUTO_INCREMENT column, the column is set to the next sequence value. Typically this is value+1, where value is the largest value for the column currently in the table. AUTO_INCREMENT sequences begin with 1.

El valor "0" funciona a menos que tengas el modo [NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero) activado.

---

También especifica la documentación que no es necesario especficar un valor para dicho campo al insertar datos en los otros campos de la fila, y que se puede insertar NULL si el campo es NOT NULL o asignar un valor específico (10, 25, 1000, ...) y la secuencia tendrá como nuevo valor el más grande de la columna.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

> No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers, unless the NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO SQL mode is enabled. If the column is declared NOT NULL, **it is also possible to assign NULL to the column to generate sequence numbers. When you insert any other value into an AUTO_INCREMENT column, the column is set to that value** and the sequence is reset so that the next automatically generated value follows sequentially from the largest column value.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha funcionado genial, lo doy como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Opción 1, pásale un NULL:

```
insert into empleados values(NULL, 'perico', 'palotes', 'de dios', 4587, 'email@email.com', 'MADR-ES', 3, 'Representante ventas')
```

Opción 2, como tú comentas, puedes especificar los campos a insertar, puedes obviar el campo id ya que sí está como auto-incremental no será necesario preocuparse de él:

```
insert into empleados (campo1,campo2,campo8) values('perico', 'palotes', 'de dios', 4587, 'email@email.com', 'MADR-ES', 3, 'Representante ventas')
```

Comment: No puedo pasarle un null puesto que en la creación está especificado como not null, y en cuanto a la opción 2 es la que quiero intentar descartar a no ser que no haya otra forma.
Voy a añadir que no puedo meter un null, gracias.

Comment: @AlvaroTauroni Sí que puedes, aunque esté como `NOT NULL` en el diseño de la tabla, no quiere decir que estés guardando un valor nulo en el campo, sí no que `NULL`  omite el valor y coge el auto-incremental que tiene por defecto. te animo a que lo pruebes.

Answer (score 0):

Cunado el campo esta definido como `auto-increment` en la BD no tienes que indicarlo, solo tienes que pasar los campos que no son `auto-increment` y la forma mas segura de hacerlo es...

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Empleados(campo1, campo2, campo3) Values(@c1, @c2, @c3)";
using(SqlCommand cmd = new Sqlcommand(query, conexion)){
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", 'perico');
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c2", 'palotes');
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c3", 'de dios');
    cmd.ExcecuteNonQuery();
}
```